Unwanted margin between keyboard and input toolbar, react native gifted chat
This is how my render function looks like there's space sometimes between keyboard and input toolbar. I am using tab navigation using expo-router and hiding the tab on this screen. Any help or suggestions are welcome, I have tried almost everything. Even if I show the bottom tab bar there's still a gap
return (
<ImageBackground
  source={assets ? assets[0] : backroundPattern}
  style={{ flex: 1, marginBottom: insets.bottom, backgroundColor: Colors.background }}
>
  <Stack.Screen
    options={{
      headerTitle: () => <Header />,
    }}
  />
  {carGroups && carGroups.length > 0 ? (
    <View style={styles.carGroupWrapper}>
      <FlatList<CometChat.Conversation>
        data={carGroups}
        style={{ paddingHorizontal: 10, paddingVertical: 5 }}
        keyExtractor={(item: unknown) => {
          const conversation = item as CometChat.Conversation;
          return conversation.getConversationId();
        }}
        renderItem={horizontalRenderItem}
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      />
    </View>
  ) : null}
  {groupMembers && groupMembers.length > 0 ? (
    <View style={styles.carGroupWrapper}>
      {groupMembers.map((member) => {
        const memberUID = member.getUid();
        if (memberUID === user?.id) {
          return null;
        }
        return (
          <Pressable style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center", padding: 10 }}>
            <View style={{ width: 40, height: 40 }}>
              <Avatar userId={member.getUid()} />
            </View>
            <Text style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>{member.getName()}</Text>
          </Pressable>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  ) : null}
  {isGalleryVisible && selectedImage && (
    <Gallery
      images={[{ url: selectedImage, imageIndex: 0 }]}
      isVisible={isGalleryVisible}
      onClose={onGalleryClose}
      setSelectedIndex={() => {}}
      selectedIndex={0}
    />
  )}
  <GiftedChat
    isTyping={isTyping}
    messages={messages}
    alignTop
    scrollToBottom
    scrollToBottomComponent={() => <Text>V</Text>}
    onSend={(messages: IMessage[]) => {
      onSend(messages, text);
      playSound();
    }}
    user={{ _id: 1, name: user?.name }}
    onInputTextChanged={(text) => {
      setText(text);
      if (text.length > 0) {
        startTyping(userId, context);
      } else if (text.length === 0) {
        endTyping(userId, context);
      }
    }}
    messagesContainerStyle={{
      paddingTop:
        carGroups && carGroups.length > 0
          ? 100
          : groupMembers && groupMembers.length > 0
          ? 60
          : 0,
    }}
    bottomOffset={insets.bottom}
    renderAvatar={null}
    minInputToolbarHeight={45}
    maxComposerHeight={100}
    infiniteScroll
    loadEarlier={hasMore}
    isLoadingEarlier={loadingMore}
    renderMessageImage={(props) => (
      <MessageImage
        {...props}
        isVisible={isGalleryVisible}
        onOpen={() => {
          if (props.currentMessage?.image) onGalleryOpen(props.currentMessage?.image);
        }}
        onClose={onGalleryClose}
      />
    )}
    renderMessageVideo={MessageVideo}
    onLoadEarlier={() => {
      fetchMessages();
    }}
    keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
    renderSystemMessage={SystemMessageText}
    renderBubble={(props) => {
      return <Bubble {...props} />;
    }}
    renderDay={(props: DayProps<IMessage>) => <Day {...props} />}
    renderMessageText={MessageText}
    renderSend={(props) => (
      <View style={styles.sendContainer}>
        {text.length > 0 && (
          <Send {...props} containerStyle={{ justifyContent: "center" }}>
            <Ionicons name="send" color={Colors.primary} size={28} />
          </Send>
        )}
        {text.length === 0 && (
          <Pressable onPress={onShowActionSheet}>
            <Ionicons name="camera-outline" color={Colors.primary} size={28} />
          </Pressable>
        )}
      </View>
    )}
    // It's there in the docs and it works, but it's not in the types
    renderTicks={RenderTicks}
    textInputProps={styles.composer}
    renderTime={RenderTime}
    listViewProps={{ keyboardDismissMode: "on-drag" }}
    renderInputToolbar={(props) => (
      <InputToolbar
        {...props}
        containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: Colors.background }}
        renderComposer={(props) => (
          <Composer
            {...props}
            textInputProps={{
              ...props,
              maxFontSizeMultiplier: 1.3,
            }}
            textInputStyle={styles.inputStyle}
          />
        )}
      />
    )}
    parsePatterns={(linkStyle) => [
      {
        type: "url",
        style: { ...linkStyle, textDecorationLine: "underline" },
        onPress: (url: string) => Linking.openURL(url),
      },
    ]}
    renderFooter={() => <TypingIndicator isTyping={isTyping} />}
  />
</ImageBackground>

);



I had to use KeyboardAvoidingView from react-native-keyboard-controller and isKeyboardInternallyHandled={false} in GiftedChat
<KeyboardAvoidingView
behavior="padding"
keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === "ios" ? headerHeight : headerHeight}
/>
